# Things to do before starting math (or physics) at university

Tags: soft-question, education

What is better to do before starting a math degree?
I was thinking that maybe I should do something like:

1. learning latex
2. learning how to use matlab

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have been studying math for almost five years now, and I've never had to use matlab...

Comment: I can't tell you how sorely I regret not learning latex sooner rather than later during undergrad.

Comment: Learn LaTeX, absolutely. MATLAB is not the most important thing in the world and also depends on what branch of mathematics you will want to focus on.

Comment: Learn [python](https://www.python.org/) or [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org). Seriously. The amount of work these tools saved me is so huge that I am at a loss for words to describe it (mostly data processing and hypothesis testing).

Comment: @PeterSheldrick If I had to learn one, I would pick python, _not_ matlab/octave. Python/ruby is more versatile (not to say that you can use it to write web services if you were unable to find math/physics-related job).

Answer (score 1):

You asked for suggestions other than learning Matlab and Latex, I have this suggestion:

### Self Study Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

1) Learn LaTeX. This can't hurt and it's pretty easy to do when done without time pressure, say like before beginning mathematics studies.

2) Be sure you know as good as you can all the usual high school stuff in mathematics. It can be hard to know *exactly* what this means, but besides asking people, surfing the internet and etc., you could begin by going in general over euclidean geometry, trigonometry, analytic geometry, exponents, fractions, logarithms, basic calculus, geometric and arithmetic sequences, word problems, basic set theory, etc.

Comment: LaTeX is a one-day affair. It's enough to know how the bare template looks like and where to find help like [this one](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/93/42). The rest one picks up along the way.

Comment: You can review all elementary mathematics in [this book](http://www.4shared.com/office/QchiFtiXba/Schaum_outline_of_elementary_m.html).

Comment: Hmmm @metacompactness: that book's contents look more like  basic junior high school  stuff (hardly), and it doesn't mention lots of stuff that many high schools cover: trigonometry, calculus (basics: tangent line, maximum/minimum problems, asymptotes, etc.), basic of complex numbers, analytic geometry (3-dimensional, say), vectors, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you suggest an excellent book/hand-out to revise high school math (I did exactly what you mentioned). Also, can you suggest a book/hand-out/website to learn LaTeX effectively?

Answer (score 1):

You could try proving theorems you took for granted(ofc don't look for the proof),since most of them have an elementary proof(with this I mean they don't need any higher math stuff to be proven)